# Not able to read content of mail using JavaMail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to read the content of mail using `JavaMail`

```
Object msg = message.getContent();
Multipart mp = (Multipart) msg;
for(int k = 0; k < mp.getCount(); k++) {
    BodyPart bp = mp.getBodyPart(k);
    if (bp.isMimeType("text/plain")) {
        String s = (String) bp.getContent();
        System.out.println("Content:" + s);
    }
    else if(bp.isMimeType("text/html")) {
        String s = (String) bp.getContent();
        System.out.println("Content:" + s);
    }
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to javax.mail.Multipart
```

How can I remove this?

Comment: Are trying to read the Email from your Email id or is it something else you're trying?

Comment: trying it from my email id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of the returned object is dependent on the content itself. The object returned for `text/plain` content is usually a `String` object. The object returned for a `multipart` content is always a `Multipart` subclass.

Use perator `instanceof`, to find out what class of the object.

```
Object content = message.getContent();  
if(content instanceof String) {  
   ...
} else if(content instanceof Multipart) {  
    ...  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```java
Object msg = message.getContent();
Multipart mp = (Multipart) msg;
```

`message.getContent()` not necessarily needs to be multipart message - if it's not multipart, it returns plain message content as a string.

```java
if (msg istanceof Multipart) {
    // your multipart handling code
} else {
    String s = (String) msg;
    System.out.println("Content:" + s);
}
```

-edit-

There is also third case, when input stream is returned: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/Part.html#getContent()

Answer (score 0):

It seems the email sent is not of Multipart content type. Check if the email has attachments first:

```
String contentType = message.getContentType();

if (contentType.contains("multipart")) {

}
```